# Syntax difference in .NET and JavaScript causing MVC validation to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to use the Data Annotation validation in my MVC application, with unobtrusive client side validation turned on.

However, the problem is that the Regex syntax is different for .NET and JavaScript. Thus, if I use a Regex validation annotation on my model property using a regex accoring to .NET syntax, the same regex string gets carried over to the client side in the `data-val-regex` property, and is used for client side validation using JavaScript.

Thus, I end up using .NET styled regex to validate using JavaScript. This results in the validation behaving differently on the client side and the server side.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: can you plesae post your regex?

Comment: Whats the regex expression that's causing the problem

Comment: I don't think specifying the exact regex would help, because it's a generic problem and I need a generic solution. There are a lot of differences in .NET regex syntax and JavaScript regex syntax, and the solution must cater to all these differences, instead of a kludge which would work for a specific type of regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, JavaScript regexes are *weak*. Very weak.
You can compare all the differences on [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refbasic.html) (and the linked pages), but you're basically limited to:

- basic constructs: `. | [] [^] [x-y] () (?:)`
- simple quantifiers: `+ * ? {n,} {n,m}`
- lazy quantifiers: `*? +? ?? {n,}? {n,m}?`
- ASCII ranges for `\w \d \s` etc
- anchors: `^ $ \b`
- numbered backreferences: `\1` (no named groups)
- lookaheads: `(?=) (?!)` (sorry, no lookbehinds at all)
- the only Unicode *feature*: `\uXXXX` (no Unicode properties)
- modifiers: `g i m y` (no `s` - use `[\s\S]` as a workaround)

and... that's about it.

If your .NET regex uses only these features you'll be fine. There's one discepancy though: .NET uses Unicode properties for `\w \d \s` and so on while JavaScript uses ASCII, so you should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` for instance to get the exact same result.

But if your .NET regex uses more features, you'll have to disable client-time validation for the impacted regex, or write a custom JS validator.

Comment: I forgot to mention: IIRC, ASP.NET implicitly anchors your regex (ie it puts it between `^(?:` and `)$`).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET adds sugar to RegExp objects, allowing naming your groups and other stuff. If you want the same regular expression be valid in back-end and front-end, then consider using a pure JavaScript regexp. This tool can help in building the regexp you need: **http://www.regexr.com/**
In ASP.Net you need to escape the backslash character, or use the `"@"` to specify a literal string. i.e.

```
//using string literal notation
var re1 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^(http:)|(\/+)");

//or escaping the backslash
var re2 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^(http:)|(\\/+)");
```